# Powershell script to batch replace links in Excel workbooks

Tags: excel, powershell

I am for quite a while, in my free time, tackling a script that can batch replace external link addresses in multiple excel files within script folder. I have learned, that you can't change external links via usual powershell to excel interaction, as these values are forced to read-only. However, there is a clever way to bypass that by converting the Excel file to a .zip archive and read/change the files inside and then rename them back to excel format.

Through learning and digging around the web, i have compiled this script function that should create a backup, rename to archive and then replace desired text within, renaming the file backwards afterwards.

'''

```
function Update-ExcelLinks($xlsxFile, $oldText, $newText) {
    # Build BAK file name
    $bakFile =  $xlsxFile -ireplace [regex]::Escape(".xlsb"), ".bak"

    # Build ZIP file name
    $zipFile =  $xlsxFile -ireplace [regex]::Escape(".xlsb"), ".zip"

    # Create temporary folder
    $parent = [System.IO.Path]::GetTempPath();
    [string] $guid = [System.Guid]::NewGuid();
    $tempFolder = Join-Path $parent $guid;
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $tempFolder;

    # Uncomment the next line to create backup before processing XLSX file
    # Copy-Item $xlsxFile $bakFile

    # Rename file to ZIP
    Rename-Item -Path $xlsxFile -NewName $zipFile

    # Not using Expand-Archive because it changes the ZIP format
    C:\7z\7za.exe x "$zipFile" -o"$tempFolder"

    # Replace old text with new text
    $fileNames = Get-ChildItem -Path $tempFolder -Recurse -Include *.xml,*.bin.rels
    foreach ($file in $fileNames)
    {
        (Get-Content -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue $file.PSPath) |
        Foreach-Object { $_ -replace $oldText, $newText } |
        Set-Content $file.PSPath
    }

    # Changing working folder because 7Zip option -w doesn't work
    Set-Location -Path $tempFolder

    # Not using Compress-Archive because it changes the ZIP format
    C:\7z\7za.exe u -r "$zipFile" *.*

    # Rename file back to XLSB
    Rename-Item -Path $zipFile -NewName $xlsxFile
}
```

'''

The problem is that it successfully interacts with the desired file and renames it, but refuses to interact with external links information within the archive at "'Excel File.zip'\xl\externalLinks_rels" directory. The link information I am trying to replace is to change the "/wk28/example_file_wk28.xlsb" with "/wk29/example_file_wk29.xlsb" by changing the wk28 string to wk29 for each external link and so on. Does anybody have experience in this field? As I am only starting my scripting adventure and can't quite diagnose the problem within this script.

Comment: Is the `externalLinks_rels` directory _hidden_ by chance? If so, try adding the `-Force` parameter to your `Get-ChildItem` call.

Comment: It is not indicated as hidden inside the .zip version of the excel file. Neither are the external link related .rels files

Comment: I see. The problem could, at least in theory, be hidden files _inside_ that directory. If the `Get-ChildItem` call isn't picking up files it should, `-Force` is still worth trying.

Comment: Hi! I have been able to try `-Force`, but it did not resolve the issue. The one factor that I am not really considering, is whether powershell can actually edit .bin.rels files. On paper they are the same as .xml and .xml.rels, which are editable by poweshell.

Comment: So they're not _text_ files? What is their format?

Comment: Windows interprets them as XML files and can open/edit them with Wordpad/Notepad as far as I understand. Judging by that, the problem with the function might happen on the stage on creating a temp folder and expanding the archive to edit the files within.